# Setting JVM parameter not affecting the size for HSQLDB in-memory database increase in size

Tags: jvm, hsqldb

I set JVM memory(JRE Parameter) size to 1024MB and by default it is 256MB. I inserted data into HSQLDB tables (size ~220MB) and i am getting the out of memory error on windows 7 machine. Though i set the size to 1024MB and i am still facing out of memory error. Please let me how to resolve this issue as this database is about to move into production site.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the size of HSQLDB tables?

The size of files that contain the database is not the same as the total Java object size of the database in memory. You can use CACHED tables for your largest tables to restrict the amount of objects loaded into memory.